# Defer and println reference issues？

Tags: go

I want to know why is there is 0 and not 1?

That is a pointer not a value.thanks guys.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i = new(int)
    defer func(i *int) {
        fmt.Printf("3:%p,%v\n", i, *i)
    }(i)
    defer fmt.Printf("2:%p,%v\n", i, *i)
    *i++
    fmt.Printf("1:%p,%v\n", i, *i)
}

//1:0x1400001c0a0,1
//2:0x1400001c0a0,0
//3:0x1400001c0a0,1
```

Comment: The **function value and parameters** of the `defer` statement are **evaluated and saved**, and then executed only once the surrounding function exits. That means that in the second print function call the `*i` is evaluated there in place and saved, and at that time its value is `0`. This behaviour is defined in the language spec [here](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deferred call's arguments are evaluated immediately, but the function call is not executed until the surrounding function returns.

In the first defer, you use the parameter i which is received when calling the func.
In the second defer fmt.Printf("2:%p,%v\n", i, *i), the value of I is already evaluated, before *i++

Comment: i see that,thanks.I don't see a return function in there.ORZ

Answer (score 3):

I hope [this simple and clear example](https://go.dev/play/p/s718ycOS9hS) will help to understand what is written in the documentation.

```
import "fmt"

func params() int {
    fmt.Println("params")
    return 0
}

func f(int) {
    fmt.Println("deferred")
}

func main() {
    defer f(params())
    fmt.Println("exit")
}
```

and the result

```
params
exit
deferred
```

Comment: thank you,i see that.I don't see a return function in there.